# Enviar dados de uma modal para outra modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho uma modal chamada **detalhes**, tenho os seguintes dados nela:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" required>  
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" required>
```

Que foram preenchidos assim:

```
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="id"]').val(id)
modal.find('.modal-body input[name="nome"]').val(nome)
```

Quando chamo a 2ª modal **alerta** pelo botão:

```
<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alterar">Salvar</button>
```

Como passar os dados dos input's (id e nome) da modal **detalhes** para a modal **alerta**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#alterar" class="modalAlerta">Salvar</button>
```

Coloque uma classe no `button`, nesse caso chamei de `modalAlerta`. Crie uma função assim:

```
$('.modalAlerta').on('click', function(){
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var id   = $("#id").val();

    $('#nome-hidden').val(nome);
    $('#id-hidden').val(id);
});
```

Dentro do modal **alerta**, coloca isso:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id-hidden" name="id-hidden">  
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="nome-hidden" name="nome-hidden">
```

Quando você clicar para abrir o modal rodará a função chamado pela `class` do botão que pegará o valor dos campos `texts` e colocará em campos `hiddens` dentro do modal.

Comment: You're the fastest men alive.